# What does "*" in "@*android:color/bright_foreground_dark" means for?

Tags: android, android-resources

The content of the corresponding xml file is "@*android:color/bright_foreground_dark" is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@*android:color/bright_foreground_dark" />
</selector>
```

My question is what does "*" used for. I haven't seen it before and can't found it in reference by myself.
thanks.

Comment: Post the link for where you found this.

Comment: I found it in Contacts app. The path is `/res/color-finger/kind_header.xml`

Answer (score 0):

In an xml layout file, the syntax for defining a color is:

`@[package:]color/filename`

Presumably, the `*` is not needed and simply matches all packages.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer here

Adding `*` just to reference to the attr that was hided.

Comment: The discussion (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650376/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-asterisk-when-referring-to-android-xml-resources) is similar to current thread.