# What is this strange character `*` in Android Toast style resources?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-styles, android-toast

I was looking at default styles of android internal widgets and accidentally I saw the following strange character `*` in `Toast` style:

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">@*android:string/config_bodyFontFamily</item>
```

that looks it is a mistake. Am I right? if so, why it is working fine and not returning any error or warning?

[image]

Comment: That's a reference to private / hidden resources within the android platform. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650376/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-asterisk-when-referring-to-android-xml-resources